# Styling React-Chartjs to fill parent column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-chartjs

I cannot seem to find a way to make React-Chartjs bar graphs fill the entire bootstrap column.

```
<Col sm={ 6 } className="text-center">
      <Panel>
          <h3 style={{color: "#bfbfbf"}}>1265</h3>
          <p>orders</p>
          <Bar width="100% !important" data={data} options={options}/>
      </Panel>
      <Panel>
          <h3 style={{color: "#bfbfbf"}}>1265</h3>
          <p>orders</p>
          <Bar style={{ width: "100% !important", height: "auto !important" }} data={data} options={options}/>
      </Panel>
</Col>
```

Result:

[image]

I would highly prefer not to set a static input as the application will be on many different size screens. Responsive size would be the goal here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the JS by utilizing the Responsive option.

```
var myChart = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: getLabels(),
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Graph1',
        data: getData(),
      }]
    },
    options: {
      'responsive' : true,
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily by set the option called "responsive" to true.

```
<Bar data={data} options={{ responsive: true }}/>
```